# Не удалять пробел до слова. Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Добрый вечер у меня есть код удаления лишних знаков в строке но мне надо чтобы до слова пробел не удалялся,не знаю как реализовать.
Вот код:

```
ALTER function [dbo].[clean_string](@p varchar(255), @s varchar(max))
returns varchar(max)
begin
set @p = '%[' + @p + ']%';
while patindex(@p, @s) > 0
set @s = replace(@s, substring(@s, patindex(@p, @s), 1), '');
return @s;
end;
```

Comment: СУБД какая? MS SQL Server?

Comment: Да ms sql Server 2017

Comment: @Dobrotiu дополните свой вопрос, примером строки и желаемым результатом

Comment: @NickProskuryakov Строка должна быть +3803580390 Миша, мой скрипт удаляет в номере разные не нужные элементыы для удобного поиска и там иногда встречается имена и т.п их мне надо оставить